# Oracle 11g invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

This query works in Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.2.0 - 64bi 
but not Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

```
select * 
  from inb_dosya_turu dosya_turu
 where dosya_turu.adi like 'S%'
   or dosya_turu.id in (select 350 from dual)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does the table `inb_dosya_turu` exist and does it have the columns `adi varchar2` and `id number`?

Comment: @muratto12: Does it give an error message? If yes, what message? Or does it return unexpected data? If yes, what data do you expect and what do you get? Please be more specific.

Comment: What Ben asked is a valid question because your sql works fine [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f99c8/1)

Comment: what happens if you simply write IN ( 350 ) and not the subselect on dual? not that by accident the dual table is corrupted (e.g. missing its X entry)

Comment: In what way does it not work?   Please describe the behaviour, including any error messages.

Comment: Why this `or dosya_turu.id in (select 350 from dual)` and why not `or dosya_turu.id = 350` or `or dosya_turu.id in (350)`? Just curious

Comment: @Ben: When I wrote same sql by replacing "or" with "and", it just works at Oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.1, too.

select * from inb_dosya_turu dosya_turu where dosya_turu.adi like 'S%' and dosya_turu.id in (select 350 from dual)

Comment: @Codo: The error is [904] ORA-00904: "DOSYA_TURU"."ADI": invalid identifier

But it is a strange error because this sql works at Oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.1.

select ADI from inb_dosya_turu dosya_turu

Comment: @Najzero: When I wrote same sql by replacing "or" with "and", it just works at Oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.1, too. 


select * from inb_dosya_turu dosya_turu where dosya_turu.adi like 'S%' and dosya_turu.id in (select 350 from dual)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these queries. There's something you're missing in your description, I'll bet. Changing the "or" into "and" should make no difference to whether you get ORA-00904 or not.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: I think like you. I tried the query at 3 different Oracle Environments. At Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.2.0 - 64bi and Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production; it works. 

But at Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production, it doesn't. 

The query with "and" works at all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this problem occurs because of language setting.
The script for language settings is below.
After I upgrade 11.2.0.3, the script has started to work correctly.
I changed the query to be queried in SCOTT schema

```
alter session set nls_sort = 'TURKISH_AI';
alter session set nls_comp = 'linguistic';

select * from SCOTT.BONUS bonusa
where bonusa.ename like 'S%'
or bonusa.JOB in (select 350 from dual)
```